# Separating a string that can have arbitrary whitespace in C

Tags: c, whitespace, c-strings

I have an array of strings and I need to separate each string into several different parts. The string may or may not have arbitrary spaces and tabs.

```
Example string:
str[0]: "   apple  e     3   a     a fruit    "
I need it to become:
word[0] = "apple"
row[0] = "e"
column[0] = "3"
direction[0] = "a"
clue[0] = "a fruit"
```

So I need to remove any leading/trailing whitespace, as well as any that are in between the fields (except for the clue field. The spaces within the clues need to be retained). I'm really not sure how to go about doing this. I have a few basic ideas, but I don't know how to go about implementing them, or if they're even do-able (new to coding and quite clueless). Everything I've tried so far either wouldn't compile, or didn't work.

My most recent attempt at pulling the first field out:

```
for (i=0; i<MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
   for (j=0; j<MAX_INPUT; j++) {
      if (isSpace(&input[i][j]) == FALSE) {
      //if whitespace is not present, find the location of the next
      //space and copy the string up til there
         static int n = j;

         for (n=0; n<MAX_INPUT; n++) {
            if (isSpace(&input[i][n]) == TRUE) {
               strncpy(word[i],&input[i][j],(n-j));
               //printf("Word[%d]: %s\n",i,word[i]);
               break;
            }
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Not too surprised that it didn't work. I haven't quite gotten my head around the problem yet. Help please?

Comment: You first set `n` to `j`, then always reset `n` to zero in the innermost loop.

Comment: It is totally possible to parse in one go, but you can trim/normalize spaces in the input before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code seems way too complicated. Here is a three-step algorithm that I would implement if I were coding this up:

1. while the current character is a space: move to the next character;
2. while the current character is not a space: append it to the output and move on to the next character;
3. repeat steps 1 & 2 until you reach the end of the input string.

Comment: This will not do the right thing for the last part (the "clue") in which spaces are allowed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could recursively replace every occurrence of "  " (two spaces) with " " (one space). It's not very efficient but will ultimately reduce any cluster of spaces to just one space, and stop there. (It gets more complicated if your input has spaces/tabs mixed).

Answer (score 0):

simply use sscanf to read 'words' separated by whitespaces:

```
char str[][100] = { "   apple  e     3   a     a fruit    ", ... }
char word[100][100],row[100][100],column[100][100],direction[100][100],clue[100][100];
int i;

for( i=0; i<...; ++i )
  sscanf(str[i],"%s%s%s%s%[^\n]",word[i],row[i],column[i],direction[i],clue[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *trimEnd(char *str){
    char *p;
    if(str == NULL || *str == '\0') return str;
    p=str+strlen(str);
    while(isspace(*--p) && p >= str){
        *p = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}

int main(){
    char str[100][100] = { "   apple  e     3   a     a fruit    " };
    char word[100][100], row[100][100], column[100][100], direction[100][100], clue[100][100];
    const char *delim= " \t";
    int i;
    const dataSize = 1;//for sample

    for(i=0;i<dataSize;++i){
        char *pwk, *p = strdup(str[i]);
        strcpy(word[i], strtok(p, delim));
        strcpy(row[i], strtok(NULL, delim));
        strcpy(column[i],strtok(NULL, delim));
        strcpy(direction[i], pwk=strtok(NULL, delim));
        pwk = pwk+strlen(pwk)+1;
        strcpy(clue[i], trimEnd(pwk+strspn(pwk, delim)));
fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG:%s,%s,%s,%s,%s.",word[i],row[i],column[i],direction[i],clue[i]);
        free(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: trimEnd() will do nasty things if strlen() happens to be zero.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `strtok_r` function.
It breaks the string to tokens, separated by whatever you choose.

```
const char *delim= " \t";
char *tok = NULL;

word[0] = strtok_r(str[0],delim,&tok);
row[0] = strtok_r(NULL,delim,&tok);
column[0] = strtok_r(NULL,delim,&tok);
direction[0] = strtok_r(NULL,delim,&tok);
clue[0] = strtok_r(NULL,"",&tok);  // delim="" - won't break by whitespace
```

Comment: What is strtok_r? It doesn't seem to be standard. strtok is sufficient already.

Comment: strtok_r is the reentrant version of strtok. The later uses static variables that make it unusable in multi-threaded situations.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I prefer to avoid `strtok`, regardless of multithreading, because it's fragile (e.g. fails if used in nested loops). I think using `strtok_r` only is good practice.

Comment: @ugoren: I think you should add those information to your answer, plus the fact that strtok_r is only available on POSIX platforms.